# Simple Camera App with AVFoundation isn't working right

Tags: objective-c, camera, ios8

I'm building Camera App, and I met some troubles after updating to iOS8.  Default camera, purchased cameras, and [RosyWriter](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple's Sample code seems working right with my iPhone5c.
But with my building app and [PBJVision](https://github.com/piemonte/PBJVision) from Github, I get images and videos that are messed up with colors like old worn out TVs without any filter on.

I am trying to make AVFoundation Camera, not using the UIImagePickerContoller.

Is it just my iPhone5c? Works fine on my iPad2.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would be better learning the fundamentals of how the AV stuff fits together rather than copying someone else's code. There are a number of WWDC videos (from a number of different years) about AVFoundation stuff and how it all fits together.

Comment: Thanks for comment, Fogmeister. I learned from the documentations, but I couldn't figure out why this is happening. So, I looked for sample codes.  Does PBJVision work fine with your iOS device? If someone else's code won't work correctly with my iPhone, doesn't it mean there is something wrong with my iPhone?

Comment: having my photos come out with colors inverted using pbjvision also - did you find a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - the original branch seems to work well but if you use the branch that combines photo and video (tap for photo, hold for video) the color is off.

**Photos with Accurate Color:**
https://github.com/piemonte/PBJVision

**Photos with Inverted Color:**
https://github.com/medvedNick/PBJVision

Not sure of a fix for the medvedNick branch but switching libraries should restore color to your photos.

The two authors discuss the issue here: https://github.com/medvedNick/PBJVision/commit/bdec195b1695f111aa1e461bb0f7d733da8ad35d